# Jest can not deal with insertAdjacentElement?

Tags: jestjs, jsdom, gulp-jest

I want to test a quite simple JS function

```
export function displaySpinner() {
    const loadingOverlayDOM = document.createElement('DIV');
    const spinner           = document.createElement('IMG');

    loadingOverlayDOM.id        = 'overlay-spinner';
    loadingOverlayDOM.className = 'content-overlay';
    spinner.className           = 'is-spinning';
    spinner.setAttribute('src', '/assets/img/svg/icons/spinner.svg');
l   loadingOverlayDOM.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', spinner);
    document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', loadingOverlayDOM);
}
```

with this (for the purpose of this issue stripped down) Jest test code:

```
test('displaySpinner displays the spinner overlay in the current page', () => {
    utils.displaySpinner();
});
```

But the test run yells at me:

```
FAIL  app/helper/utils.test.js
● utils › displaySpinner displays the spinner overlay in the current page

TypeError: loadingOverlayDOM.insertAdjacentElement is not a function

  at Object.displaySpinner (app/helper/utils.js:185:439)
  at Object.<anonymous> (app/helper/utils.test.js:87:15)
  at Promise.resolve.then.el (node_modules/p-map/index.js:42:16)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Is this an error in Jest or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I finally found the answer myself:

Jest uses **jsdom** which does not yet support the DOM function **insertAdjacentElement** (see [this issue on GitHub and it's references](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom/issues/1890)). So I'll have to wait until jsdom implements it or use another method in my JS.

You can replace the default version of jsdom with an up-to-date version (e.g. [14](https://github.com/ianschmitz/jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen)) by installing the corresponding module:

```
npm install --save-dev jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen
```

or using yarn:

```
yarn add jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen --dev
```

and then using the jest `testEnvironment` config parameter:

```
{
  "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen"
}
```

Note that if you launch jest with the `--env=jsdom` argument, this will override the config file, so you need to remove it.