# How do I properly mock a DOM so that I can test a Vue app with Jest that uses Xterm.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils, xtermjs

I have a Vue component that renders an Xterm.js terminal.

**Terminal.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="terminal"></div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Terminal } from 'xterm/lib/public/Terminal';
import { ITerminalOptions, ITheme } from 'xterm';

export default Vue.extend({
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  mounted() {
    Terminal.applyAddon(fit);
    this.term = new Terminal(opts);
    this.term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));    
  },
</script>
```

I would like to test this component.

**Terminal.test.js**

```
import Terminal from 'components/Terminal'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

describe('test', ()=>{
  const wrapper = mount(App);
});
```

When I run `jest` on this test file, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'globalCompositeOperation' of null

      45 |     this.term = new Terminal(opts);
    > 46 |     this.term.open(document.getElementById('terminal'));
```

Digging into the stack trace, I can see it has something to do with Xterm's ColorManager.

```
  at new ColorManager (node_modules/xterm/src/renderer/ColorManager.ts:94:39)
  at new Renderer (node_modules/xterm/src/renderer/Renderer.ts:41:25)
```

If I look at their code, I can see a relatively confusing thing:

[xterm.js/ColorManager.ts](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/fad6e0f9f06a47c9c102fc2e6b258bfda0998808/src/ui/ColorManager.ts)

```
  constructor(document: Document, public allowTransparency: boolean) {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // I would expect to see the "could not get rendering context"
    // error, as "ctx" shows up as "null" later, guessing from the
    // error that Jest caught
    if (!ctx) {
      throw new Error('Could not get rendering context');
    }
    this._ctx = ctx;
    // Somehow this._ctx is null here, but passed a boolean check earlier?
    this._ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
    this._litmusColor = this._ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 1, 1);
    this.colors = {
      foreground: DEFAULT_FOREGROUND,
      background: DEFAULT_BACKGROUND,
      cursor: DEFAULT_CURSOR,
      cursorAccent: DEFAULT_CURSOR_ACCENT,
      selection: DEFAULT_SELECTION,
      ansi: DEFAULT_ANSI_COLORS.slice()
    };
  }
```

I'm not quite clear on how `canvas.getContext` apparently returned something that passed the boolean check (at `if(!ctx)`) but then later caused a `cannot set globalCompositeOperation of null` error on that same variable.

I'm very confused about how I can successfully go about mock-rendering and thus testing this component - in xterm's own testing files, they appear to be creating a fake DOM using `jsdom`:

[xterm.js/ColorManager.test.ts](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/fad6e0f9f06a47c9c102fc2e6b258bfda0998808/src/ui/ColorManager.test.ts)

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    dom = new jsdom.JSDOM('');
    window = dom.window;
    document = window.document;
    (<any>window).HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = () => ({
      createLinearGradient(): any {
        return null;
      },

      fillRect(): void { },

      getImageData(): any {
        return {data: [0, 0, 0, 0xFF]};
      }
    });
    cm = new ColorManager(document, false);
});
```

But I believe that under the hood, `vue-test-utils` is also creating a fake DOM using `jsdom`. Furthermore, the documentation indicates that the `mount` function both attaches and renders the vue component.

> Creates a Wrapper that contains the mounted and rendered Vue component.

https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount

**How can I successfully mock a DOM in such a way that I can test a Vue component that implements Xterm.js, using Jest?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple reasons for this.

First of all, Jest js uses jsdom under the hood, as I suspected.

Jsdom doesn't support the canvas DOM api out of the box. First of all, you need [jest-canvas-mock](https://github.com/hustcc/jest-canvas-mock).

`npm install --save-dev jest-canvas-mock`

Then, you need to add it to the `setupFiles` portion of your jest config. Mine was in `package.json`, so I added it like so:

**package.json**

```
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": ["jest-canvas-mock"]
  }
}
```

Then, I was getting errors about the [insertAdjacentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) DOM element method. Specifically, the error was:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: _this._terminal.element.insertAdjacentElement is not a function"
```

This is because the version of jsdom used by jest is, as of today, `11.12.0` :

`npm ls jsdom`

```
└─┬ jest@24.8.0
  └─┬ jest-cli@24.8.0
    └─┬ jest-config@24.8.0
      └─┬ jest-environment-jsdom@24.8.0
        └── jsdom@11.12.0
```

Through the help of [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833331/jest-can-not-deal-with-insertadjacentelement), I discovered that at version `11.12.0`, jsdom had not implemented `insertAdjacentElement`. However, a more recent version of jsdom implemented `insertAdjacentElement` [back in July of 2018.](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1890)

[Efforts to convince the jest team](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7538) to use a more up to date version of jsdom have failed. They are unwilling to let go of node6 compatibility until the absolute last second (they claimed back in April), or alternatively don't want to implement jsdom at all anymore, and are recommending people fork their own versions of the repo if they want the feature.

Luckily, you can manually set which version of jsdom jest uses.

First, install the [jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen](https://github.com/ianschmitz/jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen) package.

`npm install --save jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen`

Then, you need to modify the `testEnvironment` property of your jest config. So, now my jest config looks like:

**package.json**

```
  "jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "setupFiles": ["jest-canvas-mock"]
  }
```

Now, I can run tests without errors.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer above which was going to be my solution but since I'm using *react-scripts* I didn't really want to eject (testEnvironment is not supported config setting). So I had a look around in source code of react-scripts how I can potentially sneak in and override testEnvironment.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/scripts/test.js

Line 124 looks quite interesting

```
resolvedEnv = resolveJestDefaultEnvironment(`jest-environment-${env}`);
```

So a brilliant idea came to my mind, no pun intended, to stick **--env=jsdom-fourteen** as command line arg. My CI command looks like this now

```
cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --coverage --env=jsdom-fourteen --testResultsProcessor=jest-teamcity-reporter
```

and it miraculously works :).

I also have setupTests.js file in src folder where I import *jest-canvas-mock* and *jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen* but before the --env hacky option the tests were spitting out the insertAdjacentElement mentioned above.

Obvs this is very hacky and it will break at some point but it's fine for now, hopefully Jest will start supporting JSDOM 14 soon.